# VS 2017 MYsql error you already have a connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Hi all I have read in several different places that this is a known issue and I cant install connector 6.98 and MySQL visual studio 1.2.7 as recommended because they specifically are for VS 2015 or earlier. Currently I am using connector 8.0.17, MySQL connector C and MySQL for VS is 1.2.8 and vs 2017 I can not add any MySQL databases to visual studio I have an existing database that I added a table to in MySQL workbench and cant configure it to show up in my vs app. I get the error you already have a usable connection it adds the table but no columns are listed and when I try to update the table in the designer I get the same error. I actually started a new app to ensure it wasn't something in the original app same issue. Help Please.

I have tried the solution listed on stack overflow due to VS 2017 when I try to install the older versions as recommended I get error saying its for vs 2015 or earlier.
I tried starting a new fresh app same error.
I tried uninstall connector and vs addin as recommended and reinstalling.

Cant really add code but can give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. I had a datasource already loaded a while ago I needed to add a new table as stated above. I have also posted this in the MySQL forum and will update you as soon as I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer but another work around may help someone else. I had an old computer with VS 2015 First I added the database to vs 2017 which created the connection string and the database with no tables. Recreated the app using vs 2015 the same name added the desired dataset copied files to usb and went back to the vs 2017 and copied the files into the vs 2017 project and now I have the missing tables. That being said if anyone figures out what the actual fix is I would like to know for future refence. Thanks Dwain